# Multiple condition in LINQ where clause

Tags: c#, .net, linq, date, where-clause

I am new to LINQ world. I'm trying to calculate sum as follows-

```
 var newSum = (from c in db.ExecutionDetails 
               join camp in db.CampaignDetailsPerExecutions 
               on c.SmsId equals camp.SmsId 
               where c.AmoCode == 5 
               && c.DateTime between date1 and date2  //error
               select camp.Poster).Sum();
```

`&&` operator in where clause gives error (red curly underline).

Comment: @IanNewson, I tried and. It gives "A query body must end with a select clause or group close".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope you are doing this in a wrong way, you have to modify the where clause like this:

```
where c.AmoCode == 5 && 
     (c.DateTime >= date1 && c.DateTime <= date2)
```

If you want to exclude the upper bounds and lower bounds of dates means remove the `=` sign from the comparison.